# How to solve the specification problem for Swift Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

```
protocol Specification {
    associatedtype T
    func isSatisfied(item : T) -> Bool
}

protocol AndSpecification {
    associatedtype T
    var arrayOfSpecs : [Specification] {set}
}
```

The aforementioned code gives the following error

> Protocol 'Specification' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

I understand that there is this problem because of associated types, which can be solved if I add a where clause. But I am at  loss to understand where and how should I use this where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think you need a `where` clause because you want the array to contain `Specification`s all with the same `T`, right? Well, protocols with associated types can't do that either!

What you can do is to have the array contain specifications all of the same type:

```
protocol AndSpecification {
    associatedtype SpecificationType : Specification
    var arrayOfSpecs : [SpecificationType] { get }
}
```

If you really like your `T` associated type, you can add one nonetheless:

```
protocol AndSpecification {
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype SpecificationType : Specification where SpecificationType.T == T
    var arrayOfSpecs : [SpecificationType] { get }
}
```

But this is quite redundant, because you could just say `AndSpecification.SpecificationType.T` instead.